# Redux isn't working in my React Native Project

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use redux to manage state within my react native project. I am using Redux dev tools and react native debugger on chrome. I can see the console.log but I can't even see the initial state in redux dev tools (I access these dev tools by pressing F12 on react native debugger). I am not sure if I've configured it correctly but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
// App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './store/store';
import Section from './components/Section';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="white" />
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              {/* <Section title="Hi">
                <Text>Hello User!</Text>
              </Section> */}
              <SignUp/>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
// SignUp.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { User, addUser, userSelector } from '../reducers/userSlice';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../hooks';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    padding: 20,
  },
});

const SignUp = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');

  const selectedUsers = useAppSelector(userSelector);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    try {
      const newUser: User = {
        name: username,
        email: email,
      };
      console.log('User successfully signed up:', newUser);
      dispatch(addUser(newUser));
      console.log('Dispatched');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error signing up:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text>Sign Up</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
      />
      <Text>Email</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
      />
      <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={handleSignUp} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

```
// store.ts
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../reducers/userSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userReducer,
  },
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
console.log('Initial state:', store.getState()); // Add this line
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

```
// reducers/userSlice.ts
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../store/store';

export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const initialState: Array<User> = [
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@email.com',
  },
];

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { addUser } = userSlice.actions;
export const userSelector = (state: RootState) => state.userReducer;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

```
// hooks.ts
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store/store';
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `devTools` property for the store? It's true by default.